# Symfony3.0.3 ChoiceType choose among entity entries via checkboxes and save the chosen to simple_array MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

**Here is the situation:**

1. I have this Entity `jobtypes` that contains `name` and `description` fields
2. I am making registration form and the user that is registering is supposed to be able to choose among the `jobtypes` entries by their name. So far so good
3. I want to list the available options (`jobtypes` entries) by checkboxes, so the user can choose one or more an then save the checked ones to a simple_array type in  MySQL.
4. I am building the form using `Symfony 3.0.3`

**The problem:**

Everything looks good, until i check the database. The chosen jobtypes are not displayed by the names but with some weird kind of path?

**Example:**

*I want* 'name1','name2',.....

*I get* Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@0000000010bec20a0000000010aaccb8

**The question**

How should i build my ->add() field in Symfony in order to get this done?

**This is what i have so far**

```
->add('interestedin', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'=>ChoiceType::class, array(
                'expanded'=>true,'multiple'=>true,'choices'=>array(
                   'class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes','choice_label'=>'name'))))
```

*this is how i get the data*

```
$interestedin = array();
$interestedin[] = $form['interestedin']->getData();
```

*and how i set it to an object*

```
$sprovider->setInterestedin($interestedin);
```

***sprovider.php***

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="interestedin", type="simple_array")
 */
private $interestedin;
```

I can't think of anything else to show you that might help you answer my question. If there is something i missed, please tell.

## **EDIT**

when i `{{ dump(sprovider.interestedin) }}`

i get

`array(1) { [0]=> object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#489 (1) { ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes)#482 (3) { ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes":private]=> int(1) ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes":private]=> string(15) "Kitchen Fitting" ["description":"AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes":private]=> string(32) "Building a kitchen from scratch." } [1]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes)#487 (3) { ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes":private]=> int(2) ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes":private]=> string(16) "Bathroom Fitting" ["description":"AppBundle\Entity\jobtypes":private]=> string(24) "Rennovate your bathroom." } } } }`

I think i'm not getting only the names of the jobs in `$interestedin`, but the whole entries. Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the deal. After crawling the internet for an answer I ended empty hands and decided to try everything.

Here is the solution:

This is the form entry

```
->add('interestedin', ChoiceType::class, array(
'expanded'=>true,'multiple'=>true,'choices'=>array_combine($interestedin,$interestedin)))
```

This is how I get the choices

```
$jobtypes = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:jobtypes')
        ->findAll();

    $interestedin = array();
    foreach($jobtypes as $jt){
        array_push($interestedin,$jt->getName());
    }
```

Results:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKLJy.jpg)

Database shows the chosen checkboxes as strings instead of the weird path. The first entry I left for comparison ( how it was before ).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store them as an array?
It looks like a [ManyToMany relation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

For simple_array type, Doctrine will store in a db field and imploded and serialized representation of objects array. You'll lose basic filtering options on a mysql side.

Comment: I am pretty new to this, so could you give an example for that please? I mean the ManyToMany relation, the controller setting and the twig implementation. Thanks